# Troubled by a sentence in a Reuters article

Tags: grammar

I am troubled by the following sentence

> According to Khanh, Vietnam has 0.7 passenger aircraft for every 1 million people in its population, compared with 7 in Malaysia and 15 in Australia.

which appears in the following Reuters article

http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/09/27/us-vietnam-dreamliners-idUSBRE98Q12H20130927

I don't think it's my fault however. In this case, it's fairly obvious that Malaysia and Australia have 7 and 15 aircrafts for every 1 million people respectively.

But assume the statistic is slightly different so that the statement becomes

> According to Khanh, Vietnam has 1 passenger aircraft for every 1 million people in its population, compared with 7 in Malaysia and 15 in Australia.

And assume we have no idea about the economy of the 3 countries, then the trouble becomes

Is it

> Malaysia and Australia have 1 aircraft for every 7 and 15 millions people respectively.

Or

> Malaysia and Australia have 7 and 15 aircrafts for every 1 million people respectively.

Do I have a valid point here?

Comment: 15 aircraft. Not 15 aircrafts.

Comment: I always use 'compared TO' and not 'compared WITH'... Maybe I missed something :/

Comment: As you have edited the sentence to creat a ratio of 1:1 million (and in the absence of background knowledge to provide context), then it is ambiguous. However when presented without context, many sentences are. I do not consider this a particularly egregious example.

Comment: I think you say it yourself, "*In this case, it's fairly obvious that Malaysia and Australia have 7 and 15 aircrafts for every 1 million people respectively.*" So there is no problem.  By making all the assumptions you concoct to change the context, you make one more by assuming the author would write the same sentence.  If the author thought his sentence would be ambiguous I'd assume he'd write a different one.

Comment: @itsols I don't care whether you use "compared to" or "compared with"; just don't say "different than" when you're done comparing. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the default assumption is that when you're comparing an explicit fraction with another implied fraction, it's the bottom number that stays the same and the top number that changes, for the simple reason that that is how people work productively with fractions.

3/6 vs. 5/6 is very easy to reason from, whereas 15/30 vs. 15/18 (the same values) is harder.

The exception would be when the top number is one:

"There is one doctor for every YYY people in Australia, whereas that number is XXX for Malaysia."